# Update the contents of a jquery UI dialog using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm using the latest versions of knockout.js and jquery. I'm trying to create a jquery dialog that opens and closes whenever an specific ko.observable has a value. I based my implementation on the code in this jsfiddle,  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WpnTU/, which I found in this Knockout.js forum, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/XIaQMNHjy7Q/BpfDU5inKVQJ.

However, this approach only works IF I include the now deprecate jquery-tmpl.js plugin (version 1.0.0pre). I've distilled my problem down to two jsfiddles, a working version (http://jsfiddle.net/LhEnV/29/), and a broken version (http://jsfiddle.net/gygh3/1/). The only difference being that jquery-tmpl.js is not included in the second version.

The root of the problem is that the observable which the dialog and its contents are dependent on isn't set when I first load the page. Thus, the properties that the template binds to aren't available, which results in an error. Including jquery-tmpl before knockout cures the problem, so I'm assuming the knockout templating engine changes it's behavior when jquery-tmpl is available. However, I don't want to rely on a deprecated plugin.

Is there a better way to bind a jquery UI dialog and it's contents to the ViewModel?

Comment: Have you tried explicit subscription to observables changes, so you place your code of showing/hiding dialog inside "subscribe" function?
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html
Refer to "Explicitly subscribing to observables" section.

Comment: No. I want to keep my DOM manipulation code in the custom binding as that seems to be the knockout best practice. Serjio's answer was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
<script id="newDialogTmpl" type="text/html">
    Add <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>?
</script>
​
```

To that:

```
<script id="newDialogTmpl" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko if: $data -->
    Add <span data-bind="text: displayName"></span>?
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

At the first time your `newThing` prop equals `null` so it's trigger refference error. You should check if `$data` is not null then render template if null - do nothing

Comment: Ah that's it! So simple. You solution is working in my jsfiddle, and more importantly it fixed the issue in my actual code. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: One more tip is that you can actually put your "if" as an option to the template binding like:  `template: { template: { name: 'newDialogTmpl', 'if': newThing, data: newThing }`, then you can leave it out of your template.  The jQuery Template engine was slightly more tolerant of the data being null than the native engine.  I put `if` in quotes, as last I checked old IE versions  didn't like the `if` keyword in KO's parsing at that level.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Is the 'if' option in the template binding documented anywhere? I don't see it in the [online documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). I'm very new to knockout.

Comment: Looks like we don't.  I'll take care of that.  For now, this post my help explain why it does exist: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-1-native-template.html